# Get last-child when child class

Tags: css, sass

Given the following DOM tree:

[image]

I need to add a box-shadow to the last `.sticky` class that is available as child on a `.list` class.

The following won't work:

```
  .list {

    .sticky:last-child { box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px #888888; }
  }
```

I'm a bit surprised I have some difficulty figuring this one out.

Comment: It's not clear, do you need to select the last `.sticky` for **every** `.list` or the last `.sticky` in the DOM? Also can you please write an example of your DOM structure instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @Arkellys Not for every list, but the last sticky overall. In the screenshot you can see for example the last sticky on the second .list item. The 2 collapsed .list items may not have a sticky child element, which makes that the selector should select the last sticky element visible in the screenshot. I can't currently copy the code because I'm at work currently, and I don't have the project here. If there is no pure css solution, I can calculate it, of course.

Comment: I think you're searching something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector and you need some js to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".sticky").last().css('box-shadow', '0 6px 4px -4px #888888');
```

Comment: No because this will select the last .list element. It may not be the last that has a sticky class as child.

Comment: I'm not using jQuery, hoped for a pure css solution. But if it's not possible I'll calculate it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
.list .sticky:last-child {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px #888888;
}
```

Comment: It's sass, that should be the same and it won't work, as all `.sticky` will be last-child.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the parent div a class, like sticky container and then target the sticky within that. This should apply the styling to the last sticky child in the div.

Example

```
<div class="list">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="sticky">Sticky1</div>
    <div class="sticky">Sticky2</div>
    <div class="sticky">Sticky3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then the css would be

```
.list {
  .container {
    .sticky:last-child { box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px #888888; }
  }
}
```

Solution using Javascript.
Not quite sure on the css side, but if using javascript you can look to style the last sticky in the parent div like so:

```
const listWrapper = document.getElementById('sticky-container')
const stickyList = listWrapper.getElementsByClassName('sticky')
const lastSticky = listWrapper.getElementsByClassName('sticky')[stickyList.length -1]
lastSticky.style.boxShadow = '0 6px 4px -4px #888888'
```

Comment: This is not what my DOM looks like. There is 1 sticky class per list, I need to identify the last sticky div that exists for a list.

Comment: If thats the case can you not do last child on list as opposed to sticky.

Comment: No because there is no last list - what I need to find is the last sticky element. There may be 10 lists, and if the 5th list contains the last sticky element, then this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `.list` and `.sticky` elements are always siblings, you could scope with a `:last-of-type` approach:

```css
.list:last-of-type .sticky:last-of-type {
    box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px #888888;
}
```

So the effect would only apply to a single element:

The last `.sticky` that is a sibling of another `.sticky` inside the last `.list` that is a sibling of another `.list`.